# Laravel 5 / L5: Set number of attempts when pushing job to a queue using Database connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have setup the Queue system in L5 using the Databse connection and after i run the migration I have two tables in my DB failed_jobs and jobs. Everything is working fine so far but when the pushed operation failed its keep going and trying to process the operation and did not delete the job on fail or inserted on  failed_jobs

```
 Queue::push(function($job) use ($id)
 {
     Account::delete($id);

     $job->delete();
 });
```

In the above example how can I set number of attempts to try if not success and then insert into failed_jobs.

I know this can be done using

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

But I want the same using the Closures as I have different cases

Answer (score 1):

You can check the number of attempts:

```
   if ($job->attempts() > 3)
{
    //
}
```

This is clearly mentioned in the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#basic-usage).

Comment: this doesn't say how it pushes the failed job into the failed_jobs table.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the maximum number of attempts on the job class itself.

If the maximum number of attempts is specified on the job, it will take precedence over the value provided on the command line.

Add this to your job class:

```
/**
* The number of times the job may be attempted.
*
* @var int
*/

public $tries = 5;
```